# UiKit Grid, Margin and Cover not working on html is loaded via ajax

Tags: javascript, html, css, uikit

I am using uikit for my project.
I am loading a html content into a webpage via ajax using the code below. The page is loaded when a select option is selected:

```
$('.myselect').change(function(){
  if($(this).val() == '1'){
    $('#ajax-content').load('http://localhost/sites/mysite/items.html');
  } 
});
```

The `items.html` contain the code below:

```
<div class="uk-child-width-1-3@s uk-text-center uk-grid" uk-grid>
    <div>
        <div class="uk-cover-container">
        <canvas width="400" height="200"></canvas>
        <img src="images/img01.jpg" alt="" uk-cover>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="uk-cover-container">
        <canvas width="400" height="200"></canvas>
        <img src="images/img02.jpg" alt="" uk-cover>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="uk-cover-container">
        <canvas width="400" height="200"></canvas>
        <img src="images/img03.jpg" alt="" uk-cover>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, when loaded, the uk-grid, uk-cover and uk-margin does not work properly as margin and column classes (e.g. uk-first-column) are not automatically added.

Is there a way to ensure these are initialized after ajax load?

Answer (score 0):

call following method right after ajax html loaded, updated the codeblock

```
$('.myselect').change(function(){
  if($(this).val() == '1'){
    $('#ajax-content').load('http://localhost/sites/mysite/items.html', function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr){
     UIkit.update(element = document.body, type = 'update');
    });
  } 
});
```

Comment: I am not familiar with javascript so I am not sure where to add the code. I added it after `$('#ajax-content').load('http://localhost/sites/mysite/items.html');` above but it did not work. What else am I missing?

Comment: I checked the browser and it brought this error: `uikit.min.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of null
    at e.update (uikit.min.js:3)
    at uikit.min.js:3
    at mi (uikit.min.js:3)
    at Object.flush (uikit.min.js:3)`

Comment: ```$('.myselect').change(function(){
  if($(this).val() == '1'){
    $('#ajax-content').load("http://localhost/sites/mysite/items.html", function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr){
     UIkit.update(element = document.body, type = 'update');
    });
  } 
});```

Comment: Thanks. But I am still getting the error I added above. I don't know what it means.